# Sum values in datatable using linq based on conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm having a datatable like mentioned below.

```
ID   Percentage  
1        50
1        30
2        0
2        100
```

**Result:**

```
ID   Percentage  
1        80
2       100
```

I tried this and it doesn't work

```
var n =  dt.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => (int)r["ID"] != "0" || (int)r["ID"] != "100")
           .Sum(r => (int)r["Percentage"]);
```

I'm new to linq and pls provide some suggestions.

Now I need to sum the percentage for each ID and the percentage for each ID should be 0 or 100 percentage.

If any one of the ID in table doesn't have 0 or 100 I need to alert. Pls suggest me how I can do this in linq and I think its the best way.

Comment: groupby statement (by ID)

Comment: If you need to "alert" then you'd be better off not using linq and just using "traditional" means

Comment: @Jack - ID column should be in groupby.

Comment: Why are you casting the Id to `(int)`. What data type is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row["ID"]
            into g
            select new
            {
                ID = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x["Percentage"].ToString()))
            };

var errorItems = result.Where(x => x.Sum != 100 && x.Sum != 0);
if (errorItems.Any())
{
    var ids = errorItems.Select(x => x.ID);
    string msg = string.Format("ID(s): [{0}] don't meet condition.", string.Join(",", ids));
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to alert if the condition is met.

Comment: Alert pops up even if percentage is 0 or 100.

Comment: @Learner well, it shouldn't. it works perfect for me. did you copy my code the exact same way?

Comment: @Learner forgot the `&& x.Sum > 0` in the `where` clause. updated answer. please try again.

Comment: @stefankmitph - Should this be `var errorItems = result.Where(x => x.Sum < 100 && x.Sum > 0);` like this `var errorItems = result.Where(x => x.Sum != 100 && x.Sum != 0);` according to OP.

Comment: @Michael it's the same, isn't it? produces the same results. but... according to OP, yes, _x != 0_ and _x != 100_. will change code.

Comment: @stefankmitph - This new code works with `!=`, thanks. Also I am showing which ID does not satisfy this condition and the below alert doesn't work. Updated my post.

Comment: @stefankmitph - This is my alert `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('not met')", true);`. I mean the alert pops up and I need to show list of ID'S.

Answer (score 2):

You are not trying get the sum of "Percentage" for the whole table so directly doing a sum on it wont give you the desired result.

You're trying to find the sum of the percentage for each ID value so you need to group it by ID.
That's what `GroupBy(g => g.Field<int>("ID"))` does. Then you take the group(g), and for each  group, you sum the "Percentage" Column of the members i.e.. .`Select(g => g.Sum(p => p.Field<int>("Percentage")))`

**Here is the complete code.**

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID") == 0 || r.Field<int>("ID") == 100).GroupBy(g => g.Field<int>("ID")).Select(g => g.Sum(p => p.Field<int>("Percentage")));
```

to put an alert message you can use Any instead of the where to check for the presence of the values

```
   if(dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.Field<int>("ID") != 0 && r.Field<int>("ID") != 100)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Alert");
    }
```

Comment: You could have added some explanation about the answer, this may solve  the problem but the op wont learn why it does.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to alert if the condition is met.

Comment: @ albertjan thank you for the suggestion, I've put in an explanation.

Comment: @Learner, sure. I've edited the answer. You can use 'Any()' to check for the condition. Also, I think you used || where you meant to use &&, correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want a new `DataTable` with the same columns as the first but with grouped percentage by ID? Then have a look at `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var groupQuery = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ID = r.Field<int>("ID"), Percentage = r.Field<int>("Percentage") })
    .Where(x => x.ID != 0 && x.ID != 100)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID);

DataTable groupingTable = dt.Clone(); // empty, same columns
foreach(var grp in groupQuery)
    groupingTable.Rows.Add(grp.Key, grp.Sum(x => x.Percentage));
```

This presumes that the type of the columns is actually `int`. If they are  strings the best way is to change it to `int`, if you can't do that you have to use `int.Parse`.

For example:

```
ID = int.Parse(r.Field<int>("ID"))`
```

---

**Update**: Although it's not clear what you want if i reread your qustion, especially:

> If any one of the ID in table doesn't have 0 or 100 I need to alert

You could use this to get all ID-groups without 0 or 100 percentage:

```
var without0Or100Perc = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ID = r.Field<int>("ID"), Percentage = r.Field<int>("Percentage") })
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(x => x.Percentage == 0 ||  x.Percentage == 100));
```

Now you can use `Any`, `FirstOrDefault` or a `foreach` loop to consume this query, so one of following approches:

```
bool anyWithout0Or100Perc = without0Or100Perc.Any();
var firstWithout0Or100Perc = without0Or100Perc.FirstOrDefault();  
anyWithout0Or100Perc = firstWithout0Or100Perc != null;
foreach (var grp in without0Or100Perc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} Percentages:{1}", 
        grp.Key,
        String.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.Percentage)));
}
```

Comment: It means after grouping the ID and in that if any one if the ID doesn't have 0 or 100, I need to check this and alert.

Comment: @Learner: so does the code in the `Update`-part of my answer work?